# How to concat dataframes but only where ID column value is both dataframes and delete the rows where IDs do not match?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Have two df like this:

```
df1:

ID   col1
1    aaa
2    bbb

df2:

ID    col2
2     ccc
3     ddd
```

I want to concat these frames only where `ID` is the same, and drop(delete) the rows where ID is not the same, how do I do this?

New df should look like this:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1,df2])

new_df:

    ID    col1    col2
    1      aaa
    2      bbb    ccc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2,on='ID',how='left')
Out[22]: 
   ID col1 col2
0   1  aaa  NaN
1   2  bbb  ccc
```

Comment: I get error `
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat` should, I convert both df to string like this `df = df.astype(str)`? One df has 500 columns other 50.

Comment: @RustyShackleford `df1.ID=df1.ID.astype(str);df2.ID=df2.ID.astype(str) `, before merge

Comment: it works but why does `merge` add `x` and `y` to end of column, why is this? like so `type`, ` type_x`,
 `type_y,`

Comment: the `x` and `y` are not allowing me to merge on these columns